# Derivatives properties and considerations

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am solving exercises on calculus and one of them is costing me a lot of work. I don't know where to start looking for information to solve it, but I think that here would be a good start. This is the exercise.

Let $f$ be a diferentiable function, where all derivatives exist, such that $f(0) = 0$, $f '(0) = 0$ and
$\forall_{x} |f''(X)| \le M$. Which of the following is not necessarily true?

(a) $f(1) \le M/2$
(b) $0$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum.
(c) $\forall_{\varepsilon > 0} \exists_{\delta> 0}$ s.t. if $x\in(\delta; \delta)$ then $|f''(X)| < \varepsilon$
(d) If $\lim_{S_n} = 0$, then $\lim f(S_n) = 0$.
(e) None of the above.

I would like to know the answer to the exercise and the reason for that answer. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If a function has a derivative, then the function must be continuous.  You are asking mathSE reviewers to respond **in a vacuum**.  What is the background of the problem?  Is it from a book or class?  If so, what theorems or previously solved problems in the book/class that **led up to this problem** do you think **might** be relevant?  Please edit your query accordingly.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.